# Why does maven use "?" as my home directory

Tags: maven, settings, environment-variables

Does anyone know why maven on Centos 5.x can't find user settings unless I use '-s'?

- Home is set to **/home/build**
- $HOME/.m2/settings.xml exists, owned by user, can be read by user
- I'm using a fresh download of mvn 3.0.4 (fails with 3.0.3 too)

I suspect something in my environment is getting in the way, but I'm not sure what.

**Can't find user Settings -- not using "-s"**

```
[build@...]$ echo $HOME; mvn clean -X|grep setting 

/home/build
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from .../apache-maven-3.0.4/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from ?/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
```

**Finds user Settings -- "-s" used**

```
[build@...]$ echo $HOME; mvn clean -X -s $HOME/.m2/settings.xml|grep setting 

/home/build
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from .../apache-maven-3.0.4/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /home/build/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
```

Thanks

Peter

Comment: have you checked that your `MAVEN_OPTS` variable doesn't have anythig strange?

Comment: Maven reads the user settings based on the `user.home` system property (This happens in the `org.apache.maven.settings.DefaultMavenSettingsBuilder` class). I suggest you to write a little java program to check if the system property is set correctly. Alternatively, you can try to execute maven with `-Duser.home=/home/build` and see if it works.

Comment: Ah, user.home system property is set to '?' (I added it to an antrun execution).  So, now all I need to do is figure out what is setting it.  I run this via a bamboo agent and must have a setting causing problems.   Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"su" command lies at the core of this particular issue.  "su" can execute commands as another user.  When used without the **"-"** it doesn't process startup scripts for that use which can lead to hybrid environments in some cases.

When writing an init.d startup script be sure to use "su -" when invoking commands or your build system user will execute using root user's environment variables (HOME included)

**Problem on Some OS because BAMBOO_USER operates with root user's environment**

```
    su $BAMBOO_USER -c "cd ${BAMBOO_HOME}; nohup java -Dbamboo.home=${BAMBOO_HOME} ... &"
```

**More proper init.d script**

```
    su - $BAMBOO_USER -c "cd ${BAMBOO_HOME}; nohup java -Dbamboo.home=${BAMBOO_HOME} ... &"
```