# Service is not registered class='interface org.eclipse.tycho.core.shared.ProxyServiceFacade'

Tags: maven, tycho

Our Jenkins has a Maven/Tycho build using Java8 that worked perfectly in February, but stopped working now in April. (Since it was not run during this interval, I'm not sure when it stopped working exactly.)

The exception that gets thrown right after downloading the p2 repositories (or maybe right in the middle) is:

```
[WARNING] Error initializing: org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver@18bef28
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service is not registered class='interface org.eclipse.tycho.core.shared.ProxyServiceFacade'
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.checkStarted (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.getService (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.getService (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.initialize (P2DependencyResolver.java:429)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service is not registered class='interface org.eclipse.tycho.core.shared.ProxyServiceFacade'
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.getService (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.getService (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.osgi.configuration.OSGiProxyConfigurator.afterFrameworkStarted (OSGiProxyConfigurator.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.equinox.embedder.internal.DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.doStart (DefaultEquinoxEmbedder.java:185)
```

...and...

```
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error notifying InjectionListener org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBeanBinder@1b6fe69 of org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.
 Reason: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service is not registered class='interface org.eclipse.tycho.core.shared.ProxyServiceFacade'
  while locating org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProvisionException.toProvisionException (InternalProvisionException.java:226)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1053)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
```

...and of course...

```
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not instantiate required component: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 1) Error notifying InjectionListener org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBeanBinder@1b6fe69 of org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.
[ERROR] Reason: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service is not registered class='interface org.eclipse.tycho.core.shared.ProxyServiceFacade'
[ERROR] while locating org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver
[ERROR] at ClassRealm[extension>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:1.3.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@647e05] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
[ERROR] while locating org.eclipse.tycho.core.DependencyResolver annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=p2)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 1 error
[ERROR] role: org.eclipse.tycho.core.DependencyResolver
[ERROR] roleHint: p2
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

My first thought was that Maven takes new releases of it's plug-ins, but there are no versions missing in the *pom.xml* and Maven does not warn about it either.

I tried updating from Tycho 0.22 to 0.26 to 1.3, but neither version worked.

I tried running the build with Maven 3.0 and 3.6, but neither worked.

I tried Java 8 with 32bit and 64bit, and Java 11.

Now I have no idea where to even start to search for the source of the problem. Can anyone shed some light on this?

(If you need some more information, just ask. The files are pretty long, so I'd rather not copy all of them into this question before narrowing down where the problem might be.)

Comment: Have you found a solution/hint to this problem? "Now I have no idea where to even start to search for the source of the problem.", I can perfectly relate to this.

Answer (score 1):

It helped for me to clean local maven repository.

Normally its located in `<User-home>/.m2`

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I think I have similar setup as yours: An Eclipse RCP project which should be build on Jenkins in a Docker container by Maven/Tycho.

The following issue gave me a hint in the right direction: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=552877

When I ran Maven with `-X` I got the following debug-output:

```
[DEBUG] Using local repository at ?/.m2/repository
```

This led me to the following question: [Why does maven use "?" as my home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465186/why-does-maven-use-as-my-home-directory)

But additionally to the `-s` argument I also needed to set the `user.home` parameter explicitly. (But that is probably only needed because I have not set the local repository location in the `settings.xml`)

This finally results in this Maven call: `mvn -B clean verify --fail-at-end -s /some/folder/settings.xml -Duser.home=/another/folder`